# TextView overlapping other components

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout, overlapping

here is my problem with my TextView :

I have a TextView that is overlapping other TextView like this :

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCffR.png)

And that's weird because when i've a long Text in the previw i've this :

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvSkK.png)

Here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_between_evenement"
        android:background="@drawable/background_evenement">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_evenement"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_sport_evenement"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_sport_evenement"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_left_icon_evenement"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_icon_evenement"
            android:src="@drawable/tennis_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/intitule"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/width_of_intitule_evenement"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_left_intitule_evenement"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_intitule_evenement"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon_evenement"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_evenement"
            android:text="That's my TextView which is too long and it's a problem because it's over other TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/choix"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/width_of_prono_evenement"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/intitule"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Marseille" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cote"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_cote_evenement"
                android:text="1.88"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_right_cote_evenement" />

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/icon_pending"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_icon_status_evenement"
                android:id="@+id/status_icon"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_status_evenement"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_status_evenement"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_right_icon_status_evenement" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I'm setting programmatically the text like this :

```
editText.setText(e.getText());
```

Thanks for your attention, and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want your textview to end where the other one starts, right?
You can change your relative layout to constraint layout and add   `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view"`
This will make your textview only end where the other one starts

Comment: You're welcome, if you can mark as the correct answer i will apreciate it